# how to retrieve records from array list when we add username and age using class

Tags: java

```
ls.add(new Employee(25,"XYZ"));
Iterator it=(Iterator) ls.iterator();

while(it.hasNext())
{
    System.out.println(" "+it);
}
```

this giving garbage value

Comment: What is `ls`? You are printing an iterator, that's probably not what you want. try `System.out.println(it.next());`

Comment: you are printing out the iterator not the value

Comment: thanks for your ans but still its giving garbage value

Comment: You seem to have forgotten to define non-garbage `toString()` method on `Employee` class. (Default `toString` on object is not garbage, by the way - it's effectively an object identity representation)

Answer (score 0):

Following changes to your code should fix the issue, assuming you have `id` and `name` fields defined in `Employee` class.

```
List<Employee> ls = new ArrayList<MergeSort.Employee>();

    ls.add(new Employee(25, "XYZ"));

    Iterator<Employee> it = ls.iterator();
    while(it.hasNext()){
        Employee employee = it.next();
        System.out.println("Id: " + employee.getId() + " Name: " + employee.getName());
    }
```

you should use iterator's `next()` method to get the elements from list.

Answer (score 0):

Using for each loop we can iterate list.

```
 ArrayList<> employees = new ArrayList<Employee>();
 employees.add(new Employee(25,"XYZ"));
 for(Employee employee: employees){
      System.out.println(e.toString());
 }
```